# How to resolve this error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.MyClassName does not represent a declared type?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am getting this error while building my Kotlin/Android application?

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor812.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:45)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.AnnotationProcessingError: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.MyClassName does not represent a declared type
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:992)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:896)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1222)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1335)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1258)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.MyClassName does not represent a declared type
        at dagger.shaded.auto.common.MoreTypes$CastingTypeVisitor.defaultAction(MoreTypes.java:948)
        at dagger.shaded.auto.common.MoreTypes$CastingTypeVisitor.defaultAction(MoreTypes.java:939)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ErrorType.accept(Type.java:2394)
        at dagger.shaded.auto.common.MoreTypes.asDeclared(MoreTypes.java:579)
        at dagger.internal.codegen.base.Keys$1.visitDeclared(Keys.java:89)
        at dagger.internal.codegen.base.Keys$1.visitDeclared(Keys.java:66)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:1151)
        at dagger.internal.codegen.base.Keys.isValidImplicitProvisionKey(Keys.java:65)
        at dagger.internal.codegen.base.Keys.isValidImplicitProvisionKey(Keys.java:50)
```

I am using dagger2 for dependency injection, in my application, the application uses a module that has a dependency on another module. What should be the correct way to resolve this dependency?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need an implementation dependency on the module you're consuming, but the recent build flag `enableAggregatingTask` will do so automatically.

Per [google/dagger#2123](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2123), bcorso responding to Kshitij09 in November 2020:

> > You mean I either app should have direct dependency (adding implementation) on :libraryB or :libraryA have api dependency on :libraryB right?
>
> Hi @Kshitij09, yes that's the current solution and we're looking into ways to improve this (see [#1991 (comment)](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1991#issuecomment-661245887))

In that same thread, [bcorso updates in September 2021](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2123#issuecomment-928064317):

> If you're using Hilt (with Gradle) the solution is to use the [Hilt Gradle plugin](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup#hilt-gradle-plugin) and then enable the [`aggregating task`](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup#aggregating-task) in your `build.gradle` modules:
>
> ```
> hilt {
>     enableAggregatingTask = true
> }
> ```

The `enableAggregatingTask` build configuration was [introduced in Dagger 2.37 in June 2021](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.37) and [enabled by default in Dagger 2.40 in October 2021](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.40).